# ¿Como comparar imagenes en MATLAB?

Tags: imagen, matlab

Vean esta imagen para que me puedan entender: http://prntscr.com/hjxd25

Quiero centrarme en OBTENER una 3ra imagen mas completa a partir:

Imagen 1: enfoca desde un angulo izquierdo.

Imagen 2: enfoca desde un angulo derecho.

CREAR una Imagen 3: Resultado de la "fusion y union" de 1 y 2.

Si alguien puede orientarme seria estupendo, soy nuevo en MatLab, gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Ronald, para preguntar debes realizarlo en base a lo definido en [ask]. Esta pregunta parece ser una tarea, agrega un [mcve].

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  el tema es demaciado amplio.

Answer (score 1):

para comparar imágenes podrias utilizar la funcion imshowpair.

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
A = imread('ruta de imagen 1')
B = imread('ruta de imagen 2')
C = imread('ruta de imagen 3')
```

recuerda que en el script que estes haciendo debes tener las imagenes, ya sea en formato png.`introducir el código aquí`

```
imshowpair(A,B,'diff')
```

puedes enccontrar documentacion aqui:

https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html